# String matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-8.4

I need to implement a regular expression (as I understand) matching in PostgreSQL 8.4. It seems regular expression matching are only available in 9.0+.

My need is:

When I give an input `14.1` I need to get these results:

```
14.1.1
14.1.2
14.1.Z
...
```

But exclude:

```
14.1.1.1
14.1.1.K
14.1.Z.3.A
...
```

The pattern is not limited to a single character. There is always a possibility that a pattern like this will be presented: `14.1.1.2K`, `14.1.Z.13.A2` etc., because the pattern is provided the user. The application has no control over the pattern (**it's not a version number**).

Any idea how to implement this in Postgres 8.4?

After one more question my issue was solved:

[Escaping a LIKE pattern or regexp string in Postgres 8.4 inside a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411869/escaping-a-like-pattern-or-regexp-string-in-postgres-8-4-inside-a-stored-procedu)

Comment: 8.4 (which is no longer maintained) has regular expressions as well: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: As always: the exact data type would help to clarify. Better yet, the table definition (`\d tbl` in psql).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Regular expression matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) has been in Postgres practically for ever, at least since version 7.1. Use the [these operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE):

```
~ !~ ~* !~*
```

For an overview, see:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10694/3684)

The point in your case seems to be to disallow more dots:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  version LIKE '14.1.%'        -- for performance
AND    version ~ '^14\.1\.[^.]+$';  -- for correct result
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=f7e5ba28e111d771bb9acbc046ac2c0d)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0a28f/420)</sub>

The `LIKE` expression is redundant, but it is going to improve performance dramatically, even without index. You should have an index, of course.

The `LIKE` expression can use a basic `text_pattern_ops` index, while the regular expression cannot, at least in Postgres 8.4.
Or with COLLATE "C" since Postgres 9.1. See:

- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)
- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

`[^.]` in the regex pattern is a character class that excludes the dot (`.`). So more characters are allowed, just no more dots.

#### Performance

To squeeze out top performance for this particular query you could add a specialized index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_special_idx ON tbl
((length(version) - length(replace(version, '.', ''))), version text_pattern_ops);
```

And use a matching query, the same as above, just replace the last line with:

```
AND   length(version) - length(replace(version, '.', '')) = 2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4a3115a417fe8ace1ce4ac66661aadf4)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8fe99b/1)</sub>

Comment: What about using arrays? `array_length(string_to_array(col, '.'), 1) = 3  and version like '14.1.%'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/286 Slightly more expensive I'd expect.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the array handling or the regex would be more expensive

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Handling alone might beat a regex in pg 8.4, but if we need to convert the string first, I am not so sure. There is a cheaper way, similar to your idea. I added a chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that definitely solved the problem. But I was going to write it in a stored procedure, but dont know how to escape the string within the stored procedure `14.1.` => `14\.1\.`

Comment: @NandakumarV: Start a *new question*  and show what you have (even if it's not working) You'll get solutions promptly. you can always link to this question for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for the advice. I have posted another question on that [Escaping a string in postgres 8.4 inside an stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411869/escaping-a-string-in-postgres-8-4-inside-an-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do regex matching, but I believe you can do like operators so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE version LIKE '14.1._';
```

Will match any row with a version of '14.1.' followed by a single character. This should match your examples. Note that this will not match just '14.1', if you needed this as well. You could do this with an OR.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE version LIKE '14.1._' OR version = '14.1';
```

Comment: The characters is not limited to a single character, code like this `14.1.23` can also come.

Comment: Also the underscore thing is it a patterm matching mechanism or something. I didnt understand how `LIKE '14.1._'` will match `14.1.2`

Comment: _ matches any single character. so would match all your examples in your question. It wont match 14.1.23.

Answer (score 0):

Regex matching should be possible with Postgresql-8.4 like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE version ~ '^14\.1\..$';
```

Comment: the backslashes are those escape sequence?