# How to exclude rows containing two words in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I'm trying to exclude rows that contain two words. In more details, I want to include rows that contain **uber**, but don't include rows that contain **uber eats**.

I'm using this condition:

```
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%'  
AND NOT (LOWER(name) LIKE '%ubereats%' AND LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%eats%')
```

But I still get some unwanted rows like the following:

```
UBER   EATS
UBER   *EATS
UBER* EATS
```

In a query, I need to exclude any of **uber eats** related ones.
In a separate query, I want only those that are related to **uber eats**.

Comment: Try OR instead of AND:  `NOT (LOWER(name) LIKE '%ubereats%' OR LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%eats%')`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need `OR` instead of `AND`. Plus parentheses due to [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) (`AND` binds stronger than `OR`):

```sql
WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%'  
AND    NOT (LOWER(name) LIKE '%ubereats%' OR
            LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%eats%')
```

Or keep the `AND` and switch to `NOT LIKE`:

```sql
WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%'  
AND    LOWER(name) NOT LIKE '%ubereats%'
AND    LOWER(name) NOT LIKE '%uber%eats%';
```

But since `%` in `LIKE` patterns stands for *0 or more characters*, `LOWER(name) LIKE '%ubereats%'` is completely redundant. So:

```sql
WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE '%uber%'  
AND    LOWER(name) NOT LIKE '%uber%eats%'
```

Or simplify altogether with regular expressions:

```sql
WHERE name ~* 'uber'  
AND   name !~* 'uber.*eats'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5530d84ceb38023a9def49149e34f166)*

See:

- [String matching in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407320/string-matching-in-postgresql/29407782#29407782)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10694/3684)

I am not sure your original expressions capture your objective precisely, though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'uber.*eats'` instead of `'uber.?eats'`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Yes, that's a closer fit to the original in the question. (Though it may be the OP really wants a more restrictive pattern, like illustrated in the fiddle with "uber has seats".)